# Window min width in WPF

Tags: .net, wpf

I have a 2 collumn grid for my application. The one has some minimum width and has `width = *` and the other has `width=auto`.. 
The problem is that when i resize the window ,when the grid has its minimum width the window shouldnt resize....
I can set min width but i should guess the width of the auto collumn and this is not good i think....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not positive what you are asking here, but taking a wild stab at it, do you just want to set the MinimumWidth of the Window?  You can certainly do that.